# Add grouped means to dataframe with grouped frequencies and proportions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this sort of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE),
  dur = sample(c(NA, rnorm(10)), 100, replace = TRUE),
  char = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

From this I can compute counts and proportions of the variable `char`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(dur) & id != lag(id)) %>%
  count(char, name = 'freq', sort = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(freq) * 100)
   char freq     prop
1     C    6 8.571429
2     M    6 8.571429
3     X    5 7.142857
4     Y    5 7.142857
5     Z    5 7.142857
6     E    4 5.714286
7     I    4 5.714286
8     K    4 5.714286
9     J    3 4.285714
10    Q    3 4.285714
... clipped
```

Now, in `df`, the `char` values also have `dur`ation values. So I want to add another column, say `mean_dur`, with the mean `dur` values grouped by `char` in `df`. Adding on something like `group_by(char)` etc. to the above code doesn't work as the variable `char` is no longer recognized. How can that be achieved?

**EDIT**:
It can be done in steps, like this:

```
# Step 1 -- make df with counts and proportions:
df1 <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(dur) & id != lag(id)) %>%
  count(char, name = 'freq', sort = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(freq) * 100)

# Step 2 -- make another df with mean dur values:
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(dur) & id != lag(id)) %>%
  group_by(char) %>%
  summarise(mean_dur = mean(dur, na.rm = TRUE))

# Step 3 -- transfer mean dur values by matching `char`in `df1`and `df2`
df1$mean_dur <- df2$mean_dur[match(df1$char, df2$char)]
```

But is there a cleaner and tidyer `dplyr` way?

**EDIT 2**:

Thanks to @Anoushiravan R's solution, from which I picked the `left_join` idea, this seems like a clean and tidy solution (and it does not require the package `janitor`):

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(dur) & id != lag(id)) %>%
  count(char, name = 'freq', sort = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(freq) * 100) %>%
  left_join(df %>%
              filter(!is.na(dur) & id != lag(id)) %>%
              group_by(char) %>%
              summarise(mean_dur = mean(dur)), by = "char")
```

Comment: Your welcome, that's my pleasure. I came up with `janitor` idea because in your previous question `prop.table` had already been used. In fact `tabyl` is very similar to `prop.table` except for the fact that it fares better within a pipe line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're prepared to give up `prop.table`, then I think this gives you what you want...

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(dur) & id != lag(id)) %>%
  group_by(char) %>% 
  summarise(
    n=n(),
    prop = 100*n/nrow(.),
    mean_dur=mean(dur, na.rm=TRUE),
    .groups="drop"
  )
# A tibble: 25 x 4
   char      n  prop mean_dur
 * <fct> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 A         6  8.82    0.158
 2 B         5  7.35   -0.144
 3 C         2  2.94    0.951
 4 D         2  2.94    0.518
 5 E         5  7.35    0.211
 6 F         3  4.41    0.333
 7 G         2  2.94    0.951
 8 H         3  4.41    0.624
 9 I         2  2.94   -0.422
10 J         2  2.94   -0.347
# … with 15 more rows
```

[It took me a while to notice you were working with random data.  `set.seed()` would have been helpful! ;=) ]

*Edited in line with comment below*

Comment: Thanks for your really clean and tidy solution! I've added `arrange(desc(prop))` to sort in descending order of `prop`

Comment: Just a quick obs: shouldn't `rm.na=TRUE` be `na.rm=TRUE`?

Comment: Yes it should.  I am *forever* mistyping that!  Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(dur) & !id == lag(id)) %>%
  tabyl(char) %>%
  rename(freq = percent) %>%
  mutate(freq = freq * 100) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  arrange(desc(freq)) %>% 
  left_join(df %>%
              filter(!is.na(dur) & id != lag(id)) %>%
              group_by(char) %>%
              summarise(mean_dur = mean(dur)), by = "char")


 char     freq   mean_dur
    T 7.894737 -0.4861708
    Z 7.894737 -0.2867046
    A 6.578947 -0.5056797
    B 5.263158  0.3513478
    E 5.263158  0.5113139
    K 5.263158 -1.4560764
    L 5.263158  0.8235192
    N 5.263158  0.9037481
    X 5.263158 -1.4669529
    C 3.947368 -0.4064762
    I 3.947368 -0.7722133
    P 3.947368 -0.1076928
    U 3.947368  0.5573875
    Y 3.947368  0.2404896
    D 2.631579  0.5942473
    F 2.631579  1.2381883
    G 2.631579 -0.2155605
    J 2.631579  1.0528329
    M 2.631579 -1.5482806
    O 2.631579  0.2813264
    S 2.631579  1.2132490
    V 2.631579  0.6157874
    H 1.315789 -1.2664754
    Q 1.315789  1.1027114
    R 1.315789  0.1288634
    W 1.315789  1.0528329
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
mean_dur <- df %>% group_by(char) %>% summarise(mean_dur=mean(dur,na.rm=T))
tab <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(dur) & id != lag(id)) %>%
  count(char, name = 'freq') %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(freq) * 100)
tab <- merge.data.frame(tab,mean_dur)
tab <- tab[order(tab$freq,decreasing = T),]

  char freq     prop    mean_dur
17    R    6 8.108108 -0.75610907
3     D    5 6.756757 -0.61657511
5     F    5 6.756757 -0.34153689
10    K    5 6.756757 -0.90688768
19    T    5 6.756757  0.33628707
6     G    4 5.405405 -0.93390134
9     J    4 5.405405  0.27471673
11    L    4 5.405405  0.87029782
13    N    4 5.405405  0.17163797
16    Q    4 5.405405 -0.67554378
22    X    4 5.405405 -0.42108346
7     H    3 4.054054  0.36290234
14    O    3 4.054054 -0.56712470
15    P    3 4.054054  0.08316665
2     C    2 2.702703 -1.15398142
4     E    2 2.702703 -0.31271923
12    M    2 2.702703 -0.96001502
18    S    2 2.702703 -0.88921047
20    U    2 2.702703  0.24299241
21    W    2 2.702703 -1.32772406
1     A    1 1.351351  0.24299241
8     I    1 1.351351 -1.07336407
23    Z    1 1.351351 -1.07336407
```